# Can git log --decorate unambiguously tell me whether the HEAD is detached?

Tags: git, git-log, git-detached-head

I know that, in Git parlance, "detached HEAD" corresponds to a state in which the symbolic reference `HEAD` is not pointing to any branch. I also know that `git branch`, for instance, will tell me whether I'm in detached-HEAD state, e.g.

```
* (detached from 9a2ef02)
  master
```

or not, e.g.

```
* master
```

However, I'd like to know if there is a way to make the output of `git log --decorate` completely *unambiguous* as to whether I'm in detached-HEAD state or not.

### Example

Say I'm on `master` and my history looks as follows:

```
4d860e9 (HEAD, master) Remove trailing whitespace
9a2ef02 Correct typo in header
f0badb5 Add to-do section to README
```

#### Case 1: unambiguous detached-HEAD state

If I run

```
git checkout 9a2ef02
```

then the output of `git log --decorate --oneline` is

```
9a2ef02 (HEAD) Correct typo in header
f0badb5 Add to-do section to README
```

Because no branch reference is listed next to `HEAD` in this output, I know for sure that I've got a detached HEAD.

#### Case 2: detached-HEAD state or not?

However, if I run

```
git checkout 4d860e9
```

then `HEAD` does not point to `master`, but *directly* to commit `4d860e9`, which `master` also points to; I've got a detached HEAD. However, there is no way to tell from the output of `git log --decorate --oneline`,

```
4d860e9 (HEAD, master) Remove trailing whitespace
9a2ef02 Correct typo in header
f0badb5 Add to-do section to README
```

because it's exactly the same as when I'm on `master`.

Is there a way, via some `git log` options, to remove that ambiguity? I haven't found a way in the `git-log` man page...

Comment: Must the answer be for `git log`? There are ways to tell whether you're in a detached HEAD state or not, for example using `git symbolic-ref HEAD`.

Comment: @GregHewgill Yes, I know about `git symbolic-ref`, but I'm asking specifically about `git log`/`git show`.

Comment: +1 for the illustrative picture

Comment: This will be possible with Git 2.4 (Q2 2015). See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29207185/6309)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Git 2.4+ (Q2 2015), `git log --decorate` will shows the exact branch associated with HEAD (or the lack thereof, for a detached HEAD).

See [commit 51ff0f2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/51ff0f27bc6bfe83da7304ef9db77f3a2a4a47b0) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster):

> ### `log`: decorate `HEAD` with branch name
>
> Currently, log decorations do not indicate which branch is checked out
> and whether `HEAD` is detached.
>
> When branch `foo` is checked out, change the "`HEAD, foo`" part of the decorations to "`HEAD -> foo`". This serves to indicate both ref decorations (helped by the spacing) as well as their relationshsip.
>
> **As a consequence, "`HEAD`" without any " `->` " denotes a detached `HEAD` now**.

---

This means [the 2.4 release notes](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e80e85a52adfda053cafc3b23058a86aff35404f#diff-2dda503b6844ed42259098aa1d9db348R4) now include the following **Backward compatibility warning(s)**:

> Output from "`git log --decorate`" (and "`%d`" format specifier used in the userformat "`--format=<string>`" parameter "`git log`" family of command takes) used to list "`HEAD`" just like other tips of branch names, separated with a comma in between. E.g.
>
> ```
> $ git log --decorate -1 master
> commit bdb0f6788fa5e3cacc4315e9ff318a27b2676ff4 (HEAD, master)
> ...
> ```
>
> This release updates the output slightly when HEAD refers to the tip of a branch whose name is also shown in the output.
> The above is shown as:
>
> ```
> $ git log --decorate -1 master
> commit bdb0f6788fa5e3cacc4315e9ff318a27b2676ff4 (HEAD -> master)
> ...
> ```

Comment: Yes; that's a welcome improvement. I believe I played [a (small) part](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/263922) in this :)

Comment: @Jubobs well done! I just don't understand why this thread (http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/263922) starts with "As of Git 2.3.0"? Was it ok *before* Git 2.3.0?

Comment: Poor choice of words on my part; Junio Hamano also got confused by the wording. What I meant is: "We're now at Git 2.3.0, and this feature has yet to be implemented."

Answer (score 2):

[Edit: since Git 2.4, well, see [VonC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29207185/1256452).  The text below is for versions of Git *before* 2.4.]

Unfortunately, no.  I keep wishing `git log`'s `--decorate` used my `HEAD=` syntax.  If it did, you would get:

```
4d860e9 (HEAD, master) Remove trailing whitespace
9a2ef02 Correct typo in header
f0badb5 Add to-do section to README
```

when you you're in detached-HEAD state, but you would get this instead:

```
4d860e9 (HEAD=master) Remove trailing whitespace
9a2ef02 Correct typo in header
f0badb5 Add to-do section to README
```

otherwise.

Comment: For information, I asked the Git dev team whether they would consider this a good feature on the mailing list: http://marc.info/?l=git&m=142412655130612&w=2

Comment: Your answer was correct at the time, but I'd like to give more visibility to the new state of affairs. Forgive me for unaccepting your answer.

Comment: @Jubobs: That's how it goes, with software that is actively changing.  Oh well. :-)