# Difference in the output of git log --decorate: (HEAD -> master) vs (HEAD, master)

Tags: git, git-log

When I get the log of a GIT repo:

```
git log --oneline --decorate --graph
```

the output is like this:

```
* 44025ed (HEAD -> master) second commit
* adf2dbb first commmit
```

In another repo, when I `git log`, I get:

```
* 435b61d (HEAD,master) bar
* 9773e52 foo
```

What is the difference between `(HEAD -> master)` and `(HEAD,master)`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## The arrow points to the current branch

An arrow to the right of `HEAD`, in the output of `git log --oneline --decorate --graph`, indicates which branch (if any) is the current one.

```
* 44025ed (HEAD -> master) second commit
```

means that the symbolic reference `HEAD` currently points to the `master` branch; in other words, you are *not* in detached-HEAD state, and the current branch is `master`.

[image]

In contrast,

```
* 44025ed (HEAD, master) second commit
```

means that the symbolic reference `HEAD` does *not* currently point to any branch, but to a commit (`44025ed`) directly; in other words, you are in detached-HEAD state. The `master` branch is only listed alongside `HEAD` because it happens to point to the same commit (`44025ed`).

[image]

## Some history

For information, this distinction was introduced in Git (2.4) shortly after I asked the following question: [Can git log --decorate unambiguously tell me whether the HEAD is detached?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25392580/can-git-log-decorate-unambiguously-tell-me-whether-the-head-is-detached)

## A small experiment (to fix ideas)

```sh
$ mkdir decorate-test
$ cd decorate-test/
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /xxxxxxx/decorate-test/.git/
$ touch README
$ git add README
$ git commit -m "Add README"
[master (root-commit) 50781c9] Add README
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 README
$ git log --oneline --decorate --graph
* 50781c9 (HEAD -> master) Add README
# Note the presence of the arrow in the output.

# Now, check out the commit directly to detach the HEAD:
$ git checkout 50781c9
Note: checking out '50781c9'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, ...

HEAD is now at 50781c9... Add README
$ git log --oneline --decorate --graph
* 50781c9 (HEAD, master) Add README
# The arrow is gone!

# Check out master again to reattach the HEAD:
$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
$ git log --oneline --decorate --graph
* 50781c9 (HEAD -> master) Add README
# The arrow is back!
```

Comment: Great explanation! So we have the come when we are in `detached-HEAD`. If I am not wrong, I saw `(HEAD, master)` also in normal state while `HEAD` points to `master` (not `detached-HEAD`). Is it possible?
PS: a big _wow_ for the historical motivation! : )

Comment: If you see `(HEAD, master)`, `HEAD` is *not* pointing to `master`; rather, `HEAD` and `master` are pointing at the same commit. I'll add pictures to my answer later today, for clarification.

Comment: So, I think this means that, when my Git log says `(HEAD -> Refactor, origin/Refactor, develop)` beside a commit hash, this means that HEAD points to Refactor, Refactor points to the commit, and remote Refactor and develop are also pointing to this commit? And (in Git bash) green branches are local and red are remote?

Comment: @Chucky Correct :)