# What does this commit message mean?

Tags: git

I am getting the following message in one of my commit message when I view my local git log.

> HEAD -> dev, origin/master, origin/dev, master

Can anybody please explain?

## Update

Finally, I've come up with an explanatory answer:

- Head -> dev: This is showing the current branch/commit the Head is pointing at
- origin/master, origin/dev: It means both the local master and dev branches are in sync with the remote branches master & dev branches
- test-delete, master: These are the name of other branches besides the dev branch in the current repository

Comment: Are you sure this a commit message?

Comment: I think it means that `HEAD` is also where dev and master are pointing to. Both are also synced with their remote origin counterparts.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25392580/can-git-log-decorate-unambiguously-tell-me-whether-the-head-is-detached

Comment: Yes I am sure. You may view the screenshot of the log here: https://imgur.com/a/cAyFB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `HEAD -> dev, origin/master, origin/dev, master`

[That would really look something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJBMe.jpg):

```
commit aa1124b89f38eed793e2b9f2d2b2ba5d80a27a20 (HEAD -> dev, origin/master, origin/dev, master)
Author: Some Person <some@person.org>
Date: Sat Apr 14 12:06:02 PDT 2018
```

That is the result of `git log --decorate` or having `log.decorate` set to `short` in your config. It shows you anything which referrers to each commit (references are things like branches and tags). This is important information for understanding the log.

This means that the local branches `dev` and `master`, plus the remote branches `origin/master` and `origin/dev` plus the special reference `HEAD` all point at commit `aa1124b89f38`.

`HEAD` is itself a special reference pointing to the currently checked out commit.

`HEAD -> dev` says `dev` is the currently checked out branch.

Having `dev` and `master` at the same commit means there are no differences between `dev` and `master`.

`origin/master` is the remote tracking branch for `master`. It keeps track of where `master` was on the remote called `origin` the last time you ran `git fetch` (or `git pull` which does a `git fetch`); Git doesn't continuously know the state of the remotes, it only looks when you ask. Having `origin/master` and `master` pointing at the same commit says you haven't committed anything to `master` since the last time you looked at `origin`.

In sum...

- All those branches point `HEAD` which is what you have checked out.
- `dev` is the currently checked out branch.
- `dev` and `master` are at the same commit, they have no differences.
- Nothing has been added to `dev` nor `master` since your last `git fetch`.

See also

- [`gitglossary`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary)
- [`gitrevisions`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions)

Answer (score 2):

`git log` (which is the underlying command for showing history) can annotate the history display in various ways. One of these is to show what branches reference a commit.

Specifically the `--decorate` option "Print out the ref names of any commits that are shown" (branches and tags are two examples of refs).